# Prevent accessing CoreData object access after deletion

Tags: uitableview, core-data, asynchronous, ios

So here's the problem I am facing. I have a UITableView backed by NSFetchedResultsController. Now at application startup I update the data source which involves making multiple network calls and processing the incoming data. If the user deletes one of the rows while the data source is being updated, accessing the deleted data in the asynchronous network callback crashes the app. How do I handle this scenario gracefully?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `isDeleted` on your objects before accessing them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using NSFetchedResultsController's memory tracking, you will be able to remove the record from your interface before the record is removed from the persistent store. Make sure to read the NSFetchedResultsChangeType of the NSFetchedResultsController's delegate, and make sure to merge the NSManagedObjectContext from the background thread (where the object is being deleted) with the NSManagedObjectContext reading the record.

A good way to determine if an object has been deleted is to check for the existing object with the current object id using existingObjectWithID:error: . This is very useful when using NSManagedObjects without an NSFetchedResultsController.

Comment: The delete will be happening on the main thread while the update will be happening on the background thread. Even if I check for existingObjectWithID:error: in the background thread, it could very well happen that the object gets deleted after the check. How do I handle that? Basically how do I resolve the delete-update conflict in favor of delete?

Comment: You have more of an architecture problem than a core data problem. This is a tricky part of working with multithreading. In the case of core data, you need to make sure your contexts are synchronized. The place where the object is being deleted on the main threads needs to monitor for changes to the object/entity being manipulated. Same thing with the background thread updating the object. This way, the object won't be allowed to be update if it was delete in the main thread. But first, take a hard look at your design. You might need a  serial queue to handle these types of operations.